# Manifest file verification Error when uploading to Firefox Marketplace

Tags: firefox-os

my Application to Firefox OS,
WebIDE's simulator can install it,
but Firefox Marketplace say that

"There was an error when deploy the manifest from the ZIP file."
(JP)「ZIP ファイルからマニフェストを展開する際にエラーが発生しました。」

what should I do to upload without the error?

Comment: sorry, it's resolved. ( then, what should I do? )

Comment: if you've resolved the error in your manifest, you can re-submit the app to the Firefox Marketplace

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally occurs when you zip the app folder instead of zipping the app folder files. Example if you open the zip file you should be able to see your `default.html` and `manifest.webapp` file. If this answer is incorrect then do let us know how you solved your problem.